# Nested $group with $lookup, mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have these 2 collections in mongodb:
the first named **packages**:

```
{
   _id: "mongo id",
   package_name : "some name",
   color_tag : "some color",
   description: "some description"
}
```

the second one name **subscriptions**:

```
{
_id: "mongo id"
package:"relates with package _id from collection above",
end_time:'time when subscription ends
}
```

I need to write a query where I can return something like this:

```
{
[month: 1{
{
package_name: 'A',
total_active: 3
},
{
package_name: 'B',
total_active: 4
},
[month: 2{
{
package_name: 'C',
total_active: 0
},
{
package_name: 'B',
total_active: 4
},
}
]
}
```

what I have done till now is this:

```
{
        $match: {
          $expr: {
              {$gt: ["$end_time", new Date()]},
          },
        },
      },
   {
      $lookup: {
                from: 'packages',
                localField: 'package',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'package',
                    },
                },
```

With this part I can get all active packages that have active subscriptions, what should I do next?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify the structure and meaning of the expected output by **providing concrete sample dataset and expected output**?

Comment: with the information provided i came up with this https://mongoplayground.net/p/kFP-Maoz9LI. I asume you need to group by year and month and then count the packages_names that are active. If this is what you need i would upload a full detailed answer.